# Logging configuring MemoryHandler in config file

Tags: python, logging

I would like to configure a MemoryHandler which I can later deploy into a variable. However, I don’t know what to set the target to so I can then print the variable with all the errors.

This is my current config file:

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=memoryHandler

[formatters]
keys=memoryFormatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=memoryHandler

[handler_memoryHandler]
class=handlers.MemoryHandler
formatter=memoryFormatter
args=(10, DEBUG)
level=ERROR
; target=

[formatter_memoryFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
datefmt=%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
```

And this is my current script:

```
import logging.config

logging.config.fileConfig(fname=r'./logger_config2.conf')
logging.info('INFO')
```

I would like something like this (pseudo-code):

```
my_flush_contents = memoryHandler.flush()
```

Comment: You need to explicitely call `setTarget` for that handler, i.e. `logging.setTarget(otherHandler)`. The target argument `otherHandler` is another handler, such as a FileHandler, StreamHandler, etc. See docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#memoryhandler.

Comment: @Nechoj thanks for your answer. However, how could I assign the output to a variable?

Comment: see answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs for StreamHandler, a way to achive your requirement to log into a variable/buffer would be:

```
import logging
import logging.config


class MyLogStream:
    """ class that implements a stream logging into a string buffer"""
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.buffer = ""

    def write(self, message):
        self.buffer += message

    def flush(self):
        # anything you like what should happen to buffer when .flush() has been called
        pass

    def get_buffer(self):
        return self.buffer



logging.config.fileConfig(fname=r'./logger_config2.conf')
logger = logging.getLogger()  # root logger

my_log_stream = MyLogStream()

for handler in logger.handlers:
    handler.setStream(my_log_stream)
    
logger.info('test')

print(my_log_stream.get_buffer())
```

Your config file needs modification:

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=streamHandler

[formatters]
keys=streamFormatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=streamHandler

[handler_streamHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=streamFormatter

[formatter_streamFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
datefmt=%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
```

A MemoryHandler is no longer required.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I ultimately went with another approach but your answer helped me a lot to figure out that other approach, thus marking yours as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I ultimately went.

```
# Config for the root logger
class RootLogger:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root_logger = self.load_config_from_yaml()

    @staticmethod
    def load_config_from_yaml():
        """
        Fetch the config in the yaml file to set up the console and file handlers
        Returns:
            logger object
        """
        with open('./logger_config1.yml', 'r') as config_yaml:
            config = yaml.safe_load(config_yaml.read())
            logging.config.dictConfig(config)
            return logging.getLogger(__name__)


# Buffer IO for error mail sending must be created manually
class BufferIO(logging.StreamHandler):
    string_io = io.StringIO()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(self.string_io)
        self.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
        self.formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

    def flush_log(self):
        """
        Fetch the string in the variable, close the IO and return the results.
        Returns:
        str
        """
        log_content = self.string_io.getvalue()
        self.string_io.close()
        return log_content


# Main class for logging
class Log(RootLogger, BufferIO):
    buffer_io = BufferIO()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.add_buffer_io_handler()

    def add_buffer_io_handler(self):
        """
        If not added, the
        Returns:

        """
        self.root_logger.addHandler(self.buffer_io)
```